# How to std::forward( *this )

Tags: c++, c++14

because I want to overload all cv and reference qualifications of a member function, I wrote myself the following macro:

```
#define DEFINE_FUNCTION(sig , functionality) \
    sig & { functionality; } \
    sig && { functionality; } \
    sig const & { functionality; } \
    sig const && { functionality; } \
    sig volatile & { functionality; } \
    sig volatile && { functionality; } \
    sig const volatile & { functionality; } \
    sig const volatile && { functionality; }
```

Unfortunately, If I want to return `*this` in a forwarding manner (that is preserving all reference and cv-qualification of the `this`-pointer within the return type, it seems, I have to manually write all 8 of those overloads.

Now to my question:
Is it possible to get the cv and reference qualified type of `*this` in a universal manner?

I have tried `decltype(auto)` as return type and

```
return std::forward<decltype(*this)>(*this);
```

but apparently, the resulting expression always resolves to an lvalue reference, even in case of a `&&`-qualified function.

Can you help me?

Comment: History contains many sad lessons. One of those is that `this` was added to the language before references. And by then it was too late to change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is a friend.

```
struct blah {
  decltype(auto) foo() & { return do_foo(*this); }
  decltype(auto) foo() && { return do_foo(std::move(*this)); }
  decltype(auto) foo() const& { return do_foo(*this); }
  decltype(auto) foo() const&& { return do_foo(std::move(*this)); }
  decltype(auto) foo() const volatile& { return do_foo(*this); }
  decltype(auto) foo() const volatile&& { return do_foo(std::move(*this)); }
  decltype(auto) foo() volatile& { return do_foo(*this); }
  decltype(auto) foo() volatile&& { return do_foo(std::move(*this)); }

  blah( const volatile blah&& b ) {}
  blah( const volatile blah& b ) {}
  blah( const blah& b ) = default;
  blah( blah&& b ) = default;
  blah() = default;

  template<class Self>
  friend blah do_foo(Self&& self) {
    std::cout << "Is reference:" << std::is_reference<Self>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << "Is const:" << std::is_const<std::remove_reference_t<Self>>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << "Is volatile:" << std::is_volatile<std::remove_reference_t<Self>>::value << "\n";
    return decltype(self)(self);
  }
};
```

test code:

```
blah{}.foo();
blah tmp;
tmp.foo();
const blah tmp2;
tmp2.foo();
```

Output:

> ```
> Is reference:0
> Is const:0
> Is volatile:0
> Is reference:1
> Is const:0
> Is volatile:0
> Is reference:1
> Is const:1
> Is volatile:0
> ```
>
> [Live example](https://ideone.com/v24Ev9).

Use the macro to implement the methods that forward to the friend, and write the friend manually.  The methods that forward to the friend could even be `template<class...Args>` if you are ok with the disadvantages of perfect forwarding.

Having less of your code that runs in a macro will be worth it.

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  -> decltype( __VA_ARGS__ ) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }

#define FORWARD_METHOD_TO_FRIEND( NAME, SELF, REF_QUAL, HELPER_NAME ) \
  template<class...Args>
  auto NAME( Args&&... args ) REF_QUAL \
  RETURNS( HELPER_NAME( SELF, std::forward<Args>(args)... ) )

#define FORWARD_CV_METHOD_TO_FRIEND( NAME, SELF, REF_QUAL, HELPER_NAME ) \
  FORWARD_METHOD_TO_FRIEND( NAME, SELF, REF_QUAL, HELPER_NAME ) \
  FORWARD_METHOD_TO_FRIEND( NAME, SELF, const REF_QUAL, HELPER_NAME ) \
  FORWARD_METHOD_TO_FRIEND( NAME, SELF, const volatile REF_QUAL, HELPER_NAME ) \
  FORWARD_METHOD_TO_FRIEND( NAME, SELF, volatile REF_QUAL, HELPER_NAME )

#define FORWARD_SELF_TO_FRIEND( NAME, HELPER_NAME ) \
  FORWARD_CV_METHOD_TO_FRIEND( NAME, *this, &, HELPER_NAME ) \
  FORWARD_CV_METHOD_TO_FRIEND( NAME, std::move(*this), &&, HELPER_NAME )
```

which shortens `blah` above to:

```
struct blah {
  FORWARD_SELF_TO_FRIEND( foo, do_foo )
  // ...
  template<class Self>
  void do_foo( Self&& self )
  {
    // some_blah.foo() invokes do_foo passing it
    // self with the proper qualifications
  }
};
```

replacing (and improving) all of the `foo()` methods.

`some_blah.foo()` now invokes `do_foo( some_blah )` with proper CV and L/R value qualifications and noexcept on `some_blah`.

`constexpr` may require some love to get right, because we don't have a conditional constexpr test in C++ right now.  Maybe simply claiming `constexpr` in the template `foo` generated is the right thing, but I'm hazy on the subject.

Comment: @CAF It doesn't make much sense, but it does make some sense, and when writing generic code you don't throw information away just because it is not a large amount of sense you are discarding.  More importantly, that is what the OP wanted.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer!